# Create Lucene.net document index with Tables/Entities having one to many relation

Tags: c#, lucene, full-text-search, lucene.net

I was trying Lucene.net for applying fulltext search and was able to use it with the helpof this link 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320219/Lucene-Net-ultra-fast-search-for-MVC-or-WebForms

but the it has an example only for some simple data

while i m having a scenario where the two entities are linked with one-to-many relation.

```
class Product
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public int Name{get;set;}
}

class Shop
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public int Name{get;set;}
  public List<Product> Products{get;set;}
}
```

now implementing/(storing this in index as a single table or doc) this is a bit tricky.

Should i create two documents for index?

but then linking would be a problem, if the search was made in `Product` and it will return result with only `Product` and not shops.

What is the way out of it? or some other way?

**--EDIT---**

need to store these 1:N related data in single document as i would be giving the search on any of the field from both the entities.

So even after the result is returned by lucene it has the id available for both entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a field in your index for each product document, which holds all shop ids.

Document (Product)

```
Name             | Shop
------------------------
Super Product XY | 1 5 7
```

Now, if you only want to search in one shop you could do something like this.

```
+Name:"Super Product" +Shop:5
```

In general it absolutely depends on your requirements. Do you need to search over all shops and find out, which shop provides a product or do you want to limit your search to a single or multiple shops.

**=== Update ===**

If you want to receive the Product-ID and the Shop-ID you can define the Fields ProductID and ShopID as "Field::STORE_YES" (C++ Variant, i don't know the .NET define).

```
(STORE_YES)|(INDEXED_TOKENIZED)| (STORE_YES)
ProductID  | Name              | ShopID
--------------------------------------
1          | Super Product XY  | 1 5 7
2          | Not good Product  | 2 5 6
--------------------------------------
```

From a found Document object you can read the fields *ProductID* and *ShopID*, which gives you all you need. *ShopID* will return as String, you can split it by space (" ") and you have an array of your ShopIDs.

Comment: Ah i just saw that also the Shop does have a name. So you want to include the shop's name into the search?

Comment: Yes, also shop's name will be stored. and user will have an option to check only for `shop` and `product` or any one of both

Comment: If you want a distinct result for Shop-Product you need to create separate index-documents for each Shop-Product relation which includes the shop's name in a separate field.

But you might think about it again, whether the user really needs this. 

If you want to execute a search over a specific shop (or more) for a product "X" to find out which shops provides the product, the above sample would work great.